# Conditional for links (JS)

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I need your technical help for a conditional that I need for a JS file (I haven't deep technial knowledge, that's why I need your help).

In the file, I print the information that is sourced in an excel file:

```
.info("<small>Name:</small><h3>{name}</h3><br>City: <b>{city}</b><br>Genre: <b>{genre}</b><br>Date: <b>{date}</b>, Time: <b>{time}</b><br>Link: <a href='{link}' target='_blank'>Link</a><br><small>Additional information:</small><br>{info}").addTo(table);
```

The point is that sometimes I don't have a 'Link' for each entry, so in the excel file I add 'Coming soon' , instead of a proper URL. As I haven't a conditional, the link produce an error 404 in the page.

How can I generate a conditional in case that the excel file doesn't provide a proper URL?

Thanks a lot for your feedback!

Generate a conditional to print proper URLs or text without a link in case the URL is missing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code and/or problem. Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and/or take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a question.

Comment: You can still try with `javascript:void(0);` as the value of the link when missing. You will still have a small issue with `target='_blank'` because it will open a new tab (with an empty page). The only solution I see to prevent that without adding a condition is to add another field in your excel file to specify the target, something like `<a href='{link}' target='{target}'>` with the target field's value `_blank` when the link exists and `_self` when there is no link

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a simple JavaScript conditional statement to check if the link is "Coming soon" and handle it accordingly. So, your code should basically work something like this:

```
if (link !== 'Coming soon') {
    infoString += "<br>Link: <a href='" + link + "' target='_blank'>Link</a><br>";
} else {
    // If the link is 'Coming soon', print a message or do something else
    infoString += "<br>No link available yet<br>";
}
```

While I'd suggest using something like the above to improve readability of your code, I have also added what your code should look like if you want the same structure. Have a look below:

```
.info("<small>Name:</small><h3>{name}</h3><br>City: <b>{city}</b><br>Genre: <b>{genre}</b><br>Date: <b>{date}</b>, Time: <b>{time}</b>" + 
      "<br>" + 
      (link !== 'Coming soon' ? "Link: <a href='" + link + "' target='_blank'>Link</a><br>" : "No link available yet<br>") +
      "<small>Additional information:</small><br>{info}")
      .addTo(table);
```

This checks if the link is an actual link or just a "Coming Soon" string. Feel free to change what the code does if the link is a "Coming Soon" string based on your preferences.